# group on 1 column and merge rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got SQL table which looks like this

Name | Field       | Value       |

---

John  | Country | USA         |
John  | City          | New York    |
John  | Street     | 5th avenue  |
Mike  | Country | UK          |
Mike  | City          | London      |
Mike  | Street    | Surrey steet|
Tim    | Country | Canada      |
Tim    | City          | Montreal    |

what I need is to group it based on Name and merge into rows (1 row per one name) like this

| Name | Country |   City          |    Street    |

---

| John | USA          | New York | 5th avenue   |
| Mike | UK             | London      | Surrey street|
| Tim   | Canada  | Montreal  | NULL         |

Does anyone get an idea how to achieve such thing?

EDIT : Fields count is dynamic. Users can add another field types, such as ZIP from GUI and it should automatically reflect in the query.

Thank you a lot in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Country' THEN value END) Country,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'City' THEN value END) City,
        MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Street' THEN value END) Street
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef28a/1)

OR by using `PIVOT` function

```
SELECT  Name, Country, City, Street
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  Name, Field, Value
            FROM    TableName
        ) data
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(Value)
            FOR Field IN (Country, City, Street)
        ) pvt
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef28a/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║ NAME ║ COUNTRY ║   CITY   ║    STREET    ║
╠══════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║ John ║ USA     ║ New York ║ 5th avenue   ║
║ Mike ║ UK      ║ London   ║ Surrey steet ║
║ Tim  ║ Canada  ║ Montreal ║ (null)       ║
╚══════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I forgot to tell that Fields count is dynamic, that's actually the biggest problem. If you can think about something it would be great.